# Turn this list into a dataframe?

Tags: r, xml, list, parsing

I have this list, which I created thru the following R code:

I did with `t1 <- xmlParse('xmlFile.xml')`

```
xml_data <- xmlToList(t1)

ns <- c(m=xmlNamespaceDefinitions(doc)[[1]]$uri)

top = xmlRoot(t1)

rootNode <- xmlRoot(t1) (REPORT is the returned root note)

rootNode[1]

xmlName(top)

names(top)
```

> str(xml_data)

```
List of 76

$ TRAFFICREPORTTIMESTAMP         : chr "2003-06-12T17:49:54.109951"

$ AGENCYIDENTIFIER            : chr "MILWAUKEE"

$ AGENCYNAME                  : chr "MILWAUKEE City Fire Department"

$ APPROVALDATA                :List of 17

  ..$ AGENCY                 : chr "MILWAUKEE"

  ..$ APPROVALDATE           : chr "2002-01-13T08:19:48"

  ..$ CADSENT                :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  ..$ CADSENT_DATE           :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  ..$ CC_NUMBER              : chr "1234256125"

  ..$ DATE_INITIATED2        : chr "2017-03-27T18:21:25"

  ..$ GROUP_NUMBER           : chr "2512"

 ..$ HISTORICALAPPROVALDATAs:Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  ..$ INCIDENT_DATE          : chr "2017-03-27T00:00:00"

  ..$ INVESTIGATOR           :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  ..$ REPORT_TYPE            : chr "TRAFFIC"

  ..$ SEQ_GUID               : chr "123456ABCD"

  ..$ STATUS_CHANGE_DATE     : chr "2002-02-13T03:19:45"

  ..$ STATUS_ID              : chr "3"

  ..$ STEP_NUMBER            : chr "1"

  ..$ TR_USERNAME            : chr "MILWAUKEEF000"

  ..$ UNIT_CODE              : chr "999"

$ AREA                        : chr "UNK"

$ CIRCUMSTANCES               :List of 4

  ..$ CIRCUMSTANCE:List of 6

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCECODE: chr "00"

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCEID  : chr "4860823"

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCETYPE: chr "Weather"

  .. ..$ PERSONID        :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ REPORTNUMBER    : chr "123456ABCD"

  .. ..$ VEHICLEID       :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  ..$ CIRCUMSTANCE:List of 6

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCECODE: chr "00"

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCEID  : chr "4860824"

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCETYPE: chr "Road"

  .. ..$ PERSONID        :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ REPORTNUMBER    : chr "123456ABCD"

  .. ..$ VEHICLEID       :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  ..$ CIRCUMSTANCE:List of 6

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCECODE: chr "00"

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCEID  : chr "4860515"

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCETYPE: chr "Person"

  .. ..$ PERSONID        : chr "cxxxf-5xdf-49xe-b6x33-2xxx3dz"

  .. ..$ REPORTNUMBER    : chr "123456ABCD"

  .. ..$ VEHICLEID       :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  ..$ CIRCUMSTANCE:List of 6

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCECODE: chr "00"

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCEID  : chr "4777726"

  .. ..$ CIRCUMSTANCETYPE: chr "Person"

  .. ..$ PERSONID        : chr "cxxxf-5xdf-49xe-b6x33-2xxx3dz"

  .. ..$ REPORTNUMBER    : chr "123456ABCD"

  .. ..$ VEHICLEID       :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

$ COLLISIONTYPE               : chr "09"

  $ People                      :List of 5

  ..$ TRAFFICPERSON:List of 21

  .. ..$ ADDRESS      : chr "1234 SANTA CLAUSE LN"

  .. ..$ CITATIONCODES: NULL

  .. ..$ CITY         : chr "NORTH POLE"

  .. ..$ COMPANY      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ COUNTRY      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ COUNTY       :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLCLASS      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLNUMBER     : chr "DLSTR"

  .. ..$ DLSTATE      : chr "FL"

  .. ..$ DOB          : chr "1563-01-20T00:00:00"

  .. ..$ FIRSTNAME    : chr "BILLY"

  .. ..$ HOMEPHONE    :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ LASTNAME     : chr "BILLY"

  .. ..$ MIDDLENAME   : chr "BILLY"

  .. ..$ OTHERPHONE   :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ PERSONID     : chr "cxxxf-5xdf-49xe-b6x33-2xxx3dz"

  .. ..$ RACE         :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ REPORTNUMBER : chr "123456ABCD"

  .. ..$ SEX          : chr "M"

  .. ..$ STATE        : chr "MI"

  .. ..$ ZIP          : chr "00000"

 ..$ TRAFFICPERSON:List of 21

  .. ..$ ADDRESS      : chr "ADDRSTRING"

  .. ..$ CITATIONCODES: NULL

  .. ..$ CITY         : chr "CITYSTRING"

  .. ..$ COMPANY      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ COUNTRY      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ COUNTY       :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLCLASS      : chr "A"

  .. ..$ DLNUMBER     : chr "DLSTR"

  .. ..$ DLSTATE      : chr "MI"

  .. ..$ DOB          : chr "1850-05-04T00:00:00"

  .. ..$ FIRSTNAME    : chr "MJACKSON"

  .. ..$ HOMEPHONE    :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ LASTNAME     : chr "JEAN"

  .. ..$ MIDDLENAME   : chr "BILLY"

  .. ..$ OTHERPHONE   :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ PERSONID     : chr "cxxxf-5xdf-49xe-b6x33-2xxx3dz"

  .. ..$ RACE         :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ REPORTNUMBER : chr "123456ABCD"

  .. ..$ SEX          : chr "M"

  .. ..$ STATE        : chr "MI"

  .. ..$ ZIP          : chr "00000"

  ..$ TRAFFICPERSON:List of 21

  .. ..$ ADDRESS      : chr "1000 THIS IS ADDRESS LANE"

  .. ..$ CITATIONCODES: NULL

  .. ..$ CITY         : chr "PROMISED LAND CITY"

  .. ..$ COMPANY      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ COUNTRY      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ COUNTY       :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLCLASS      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLNUMBER     :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLSTATE      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DOB          :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ FIRSTNAME    : chr "BIG"

  .. ..$ HOMEPHONE    :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ LASTNAME     : chr "LASTNAMESTR"

  .. ..$ MIDDLENAME   : chr "LOVEMURICA"

  .. ..$ OTHERPHONE   : chr "0000000000"

  .. ..$ PERSONID     : chr "cxxxf-5xdf-49xe-b6x33-2xxx3dz"

  .. ..$ RACE         :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ REPORTNUMBER : chr "123456ABCD"

 .. ..$ SEX          :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ STATE        : chr "MI"

  .. ..$ ZIP          : chr "00000"

  ..$ TRAFFICPERSON:List of 21

  .. ..$ ADDRESS      : chr "0"

  .. ..$ CITATIONCODES: NULL

  .. ..$ CITY         : chr "0"

  .. ..$ COMPANY      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ COUNTRY      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ COUNTY       :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLCLASS      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLNUMBER     :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLSTATE      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DOB          :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ FIRSTNAME    : chr "BILLY"

  .. ..$ HOMEPHONE    : chr "0000000000"

  .. ..$ LASTNAME     : chr "BOB"

  .. ..$ MIDDLENAME   :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ OTHERPHONE   :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ PERSONID     : chr "cxxxf-5xdf-49xe-b6x33-2xxx3dz"

  .. ..$ RACE         :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ REPORTNUMBER : chr "123456ABCD"

  .. ..$ SEX          :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ STATE        : chr "US"

  .. ..$ ZIP          : chr "0"

  ..$ TRAFFICPERSON:List of 21

  .. ..$ ADDRESS      : chr "0"

  .. ..$ CITATIONCODES: NULL

  .. ..$ CITY         : chr "0"

  .. ..$ COMPANY      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ COUNTRY      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ COUNTY       :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLCLASS      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLNUMBER     :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DLSTATE      :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ DOB          :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ FIRSTNAME    : chr "JOHN"

  .. ..$ HOMEPHONE    : chr "0000000000"

  .. ..$ LASTNAME     : chr "JINGLEHIMERSMITH"

  .. ..$ MIDDLENAME   :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ OTHERPHONE   :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ PERSONID     : chr "cxxxf-5xdf-49xe-b6x33-2xxx3dz"

  .. ..$ RACE         :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ REPORTNUMBER : chr "123456ABCD"

  .. ..$ SEX          :Formal class 'XMLAttributes' [package "XML"] with 1 slot

  .. .. .. ..@ .Data: chr "true"

  .. ..$ STATE        : chr "US"

  .. ..$ ZIP          : chr "0"
```

How would I turn a list with this nested structure into a dataframe? Thank you

I am unsure how I would turn this xmlParsed file that I got locally into an actual XML doc with different tables (as you can see form the list some of the elements have subelements.

Comment: please edit to use `dput()` instead of `str()`

Comment: it would be helpful to include what you want the desired output to look like, that is, what structure are you looking for in a data.frame? (e.g. type out an example of how the first few rows/cols should look)